node-red connection with cloud firestore and service account account credential issue - node-red error 5 not found
Here's the workflow:

I created a project in google cloud platform.
I went to Firebase, created a Firebase project, and then set up Cloud Fire store.
I navigated to the google cloud platform service account and selected fire base- admin  since it was the only available option.
I created a  file key for this service account.
In Node-RED, I used the Fires tore out node and entered the credentials in the admin config.

However, I'm encountering an "Error 5: Not Found" message, and I don't understand why it's not working. the  Firebase project is base on the project id of google cloud platform i had created earlier
i want to connect my node-red fireout to firestore , and add some data to my collection
